# Un able to execute Appium script on real Device

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, automation, appium

What I did so far:

1. Setup Appium server and started the same.
2. Downloaded Android SDK and created virtual devices(cloned Nexus 5 in my case)
3. Executed Java script on Emulator created ( on default Browser: "Browser" -- Script executed successfully
4. Connected real nexus --> it has chrome as native browser
5. Updated the device name in script and updated browser as "Chrome" Executed Script -> The browser opens up -->

Issues:

> 1. It always prompts me to accept google terms and conditions for chrome and then wants me to login. When i try manually - it does not
>      prompt for same... any solution/workaround to get rid of it?
> 2. Once i manually accept the terms and conditions and sign in --> the browser just shows data:; and does not get re directed : error shows: 
>      *A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver) (WARNING: The server did not
>      provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 68.98
>      seconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision:
>      '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23
>      13:11:40' System info: host: 'ABT-JS-H03104.local', ip: 'X.X.X.X',
>      os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5',
>      java.version: '1.7.0_71' Driver info:
>      io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver*

```
**Server log:** 
*debug] [CHROMEDRIVER] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267517) on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. info: [debug] Making http request with opts: {"url":"http: //127-0-0-1:9515/wd/hub/session","method":"POST","json":{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"<devicename>"}}}} info: [debug] Could not connect yet; retrying info: [debug] Making http request with opts: {"url":"http: //127-0-0-1:9515/wd/hub/session","method":"POST","json":{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"<DeviceName>"}}}} error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"a925aadb8215cdb1b5b31e4d17562398","status":100,"value":{"message":"chrome not reachable\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64)"}} info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver info: [debug] Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/chromedriver.js:222:12)
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:121:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/request/request.js:121:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/request/request.js:985:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/request/request.js:936:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13) info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)","origValue":"Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver"},"sessionId":null}*
```

What I tried so dar:
I have tried updating different versions of chrome driver in my local appium folder

Any Help or direction ??

Comment: *message":"chrome not reachable* should be the exact cause yo u shall look for.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome do you have on your phone? I was having this problem until I updated the browser. Chromedriver requires a minimum version of Chrome 30.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android

Comment: Regret delayed response, i guess i missed the notification of this response. My device (Nexus5) has chrome version 30.0 and chrome driver i am using is 2.13

Comment: Also just wanted to bring up that i am using appium server from source